# Detect end of text file, reading using fgetc

Tags: c, file, eof

I have a text file. I am writing a program to read from the file using **fgetc** and put in a two dimensional buffer.

After printing the contents of file, it's printing some junk until end of buffer despite having put the check for EOF and ERROR as shown below. How can I get it done?

```
    unsigned char ch;
    while(ch=fgetc(fp))
    {
       if(ch== EOF || ch==NULL)
       break;
       //OTHER INSTRUCTIONS
    }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Can try changing the `unsigned char` to `char`? `EOF` is -1, so it can't be stored in an `unsigned` type.

Comment: @rcs The proper return type of `fgetc()` is of course `int`, the point is that the type needs to be large enough to hold every valid character, *and* `EOF` which is not a character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EOF` is an Integer with the value `-1`.

When you do `ch=fgetc(fp)` in the while loop, you read into an `unsigned char`, that can by definition not be signed, so it can't be equal to `-1`.

A solution could be to read into an integer and to cast it after having checked for `EOF`.

```
int ch;
while(ch=fgetc(fp))
{
   if(ch == EOF)
   break;
   //OTHER INSTRUCTIONS
}
```

Refer to [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgetc.htm) for a sample of how it should be implemented.

Comment: No need to check for `NULL` here (although it should be `0`). The variable `ch` will be `0` only if it reads one from the file, and the OP assured "I have a text file".

Comment: @Jongware you are right, I removed it. I did just take the sample from the OP and change `unsigned char` to `int` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Reading from the open file (till the end of file) should be done like this:

```
int ch;
while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
   /* your code */
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Your program has some errors.Use the following program,it is correct program to print all the data of any file:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char c;
    fp=fopen("filename.txt","r");
    clrscr();
    c=fgetc(fp);
    while(c!=EOF)
    {
        printf("%c",c);
        c=fgetc(fp);
    }
    getch();
}
```

**I hope that it will help you**

Comment: Using `char c;` will be problematic in some platforms. Always choose `int c` since the return type of `fgetc` is `int.