# String arrays in C segmentation fault

Tags: c

I'm trying to create an array of strings and pass strings to this array.

```
struct node {
    int vertex_no;

};

int main() {
    char city1[100], city2[100], buffer[999];
    int distance;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("cities.txt", "r+");
    if(fp == NULL)
        perror("Error");
    //Change - characters with space
    while(1) {
        char ch = fgetc(fp);
        if(ch == '-') {
            fseek(fp, ftell(fp)-1, SEEK_SET);
            fputc(' ', fp);
        }

        if(ch == EOF)
            break;
    }

    //Get to beginning of the file
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    //Pass first line
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp);

    int i, j, v = 0;
    char cities[100][100];
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            cities[i][j] = '\n';
    int vertices = 0;
    int add = 1;
    //Find how many vertices we have
    while(fscanf(fp, "%s %s %d", city1, city2, &distance) == 3) {
        if(cities[0][0] == '\n') {
            strcpy(cities[0], city1);
            strcpy(cities[1], city2);
            v = 2;
        }
        for(i = 0; cities[i][0] != '\n'; i++) {
            //Search city1 inside cities array
            if( strcmp(cities[i], city1) == 0 ) {
                add = 0;                
                break;
            }
            //If not found add it to array
            if(add) {
                strcpy(cities[v], city1);
                v++;
            }
            //Same search for city2
            add = 1;
            if( strcmp(cities[i], city2) == 0 ) {
                add = 0;                
                break;
            }
            //If not found add it to array
            if(add) {
                strcpy(cities[v], city2);
                v++;
            }
        }               
    }

    for(i=0;cities[i][0] != '\n';i++)
        printf("City no.%d = %s\n", i, cities[i]);
    printf("Last city1, city2 and distance: %s, %s, %d", city1, city2, distance);
    return 0;
}
```

As a result I get

```
segmentation fault(core dumped)
```

When I try to do something like this

```
char *test = NULL;
strcpy(test, "hello");
return 0;
```

I get the same segmentation fault again. Although when allocate space like this:

```
char *test = (char *) malloc(100);
```

There is no problem. But when I do like this:

```
char test[100];
```

There is also no problem. So that's why I don't understand the reason of getting segmentation fault even tho I used

```
char strings[100][100];
```

instead of

```
char *strings[100];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Definitive List of Common Reasons for Segmentation Faults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047452/definitive-list-of-common-reasons-for-segmentation-faults)

Comment: Use a debugger to find out *where* the segfault occurs. Examine variables involved in the failed operation.

Comment: *Where* do you get the crash? Have you tried running in a debugger to catch the crash "in action"? Please do that to locate where in *your* code the crash happens, as well as to examine the values of all involved variables when it happens. If you still can't figure it out yourself then please edit your question to include that information so we can better help you.

Comment: `for(i = 0; cities[i][0] != '\n'; i++) {` runs possible endless

Comment: Your strings don't have null terminators.

Comment: All the `strXXX()` functions work on null-terminated strings, but you don't have them.

Comment: It seems like you're using `\n` when you should have been using `\0`.

Comment: `char ch = fgetc(fp);` is [wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23513961/detect-end-of-text-file-reading-using-fgetc).

Comment: @StoryTeller List of common reasons for seg faults is not an exact duplicate of this question.

Comment: @2501 - Neither is the definitive reason of unresolved external symbol errors an exact duplicate for that type of question. "Exact" duplicates are rare.

Comment: @StoryTeller Why are you closing it then?

Comment: @2501 - Because the OP can get their question answered there.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.  You also need to `#include` at least one standard header file for it to be complete, too.

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  Amongst other reasons, it is missing the necessary `#include` statements

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 100.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: regarding this line:`while(fscanf(fp, "%s %s %d", city1, city2, &distance) == 3)`  something needs to keep track of how many entries are being used in the `cities[][]` array so the code will not try to add more than 100 vertices.  this seems to be the variable `v`, so the line should be: `while( v<100 && fscanf(fp, "%s %s %d", city1, city2, &distance) == 3)`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, when using the "%s" input conversion specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer. this is to avoid buffer overflow, which would be undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event and/or corrupt the following data.

Comment: the input: `distance` is not saved, nor associated with the cities that it was read with. So the code contains a major logic flaw.

Comment: actually, this: `char test[100];` is a problem because it only declares an single array of 100 characters.  I.E. only has a location for a single city string

Answer (score 0):

Following allocates a single pointer and sets that pointer to point to a single array of 100 characters.  I.E. no place to insert 100 city strings.

```
char *test = NULL;
strcpy(test, "hello");
return 0;

....
char *test = (char *) malloc(100);
....
```

Following declares an array of 100 bytes with no room for 100 city strings

```
char test[100];
```

Following declares an array of 100 character arrays, of which each array is 100 bytes long

```
char strings[100][100];
```

Following declares an array of 100 pointers to char, not 100 character strings. So you would need to 'malloc' room for each city string and insert that pointer into the appropriate offset into the array.

```
char *strings[100];
```